# Product details modal with url

Tags: javascript, html, url, modal-dialog

I have a basic search app where the user fills out a search filter then they click find, and a bunch of products show up in the results. Then when they click a product, I want to show the product details in a modal, but I also want there to be product id in the url so that they can share a link to the product details page for that product. So i guess if they share a product link to a friend, it would open the results page with no results, but a modal over top of it with the product.

I want to use a modal because it doesn't ever make the user lose their place in the search and seems a bit easier to use to go between lots of products/could potentially click across arrows to go to the next/previous product in the search results.

Is it possible to use a modal for the product details and still be able to share a link to the product details page for that specific product? Or do i need to use a traditional page to use the product specific url?

**EDIT: It is in an Angular 2 app**

Comment: Are you using bootstrap for the modal? Are you using jQuery and/or angularjs?

Comment: You can use AngularJS's Router for that purpose.

Comment: @ErolKESKİN Wow great, I'm using Angular 2

Comment: @AlexK I'm using Angular 2